# Salesforce Mobile SDK Community Registration

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-ios-sdk

I am developing a mobile application for one of our client using Salesforce SDk. I haven't found any documentation regarding the community registration vai Salsforce SDK. Is this possible? Because when i complete the registration from "Not a member" link the page is still loading in the webview , not getting redirected to the application ( to mobile). Is there any way to accomplish registration via SDK?